# serialization in c# calling methods

Tags: c#, vb.net, network-programming

This code is from the book "Network Programming in .net using C# and VB.net"

what i dont understand is that how
_issuanceDate,_deliveryDate,_invoiceDate,_paymentDate is being set. in the code there is no explicit setting of value , yet the XML file contains dates of all, and also how the purchaseorder class methods are getting called ?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
    using System.IO;

    namespace Serialization
    {
         public partial class Form1 : Form
         {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        company vendor = new company();
        company buyer = new company();
        lineItem Goods = new lineItem();
        purchaseOrder po = new purchaseOrder();

        vendor.name = "Acme";
        buyer.name = "Wiley E Coyete";

        Goods.description = "Anti Road Runner Gun";
        Goods.quantity = 1;
        Goods.cost = 599.99;

        po.items = new lineItem[1];
        po.items[0] = Goods;
        po.buyer = buyer;
        po.vendor = vendor;



        SoapFormatter sf = new SoapFormatter();
        FileStream fs = File.Create("C:\\Users\\S Ghosh\\Desktop\\po.xml");
        sf.Serialize(fs, po);
        fs.Close();            
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SoapFormatter sf = new SoapFormatter();
        FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("C:\\Users\\S Ghosh\\Desktop\\po.xml");
        purchaseOrder po = (purchaseOrder)sf.Deserialize(fs);
        fs.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Customer is " + po.buyer.name);
        po.show();
    }
}

public enum purchaseOrderStates
{

    DELIVERED,
    ISSUED,
    INVOICED,
    PAID
}

[Serializable()]
public class company
{
    public string name;
    public string address;
    public string phone;
}

[Serializable()]
public class lineItem
{
    public string description;
    public int quantity;
    public double cost;
}
[Serializable()]
public class purchaseOrder
{
    private purchaseOrderStates _purchaseOrderStatus;
    private DateTime _issuanceDate;
    private DateTime _deliveryDate;
    private DateTime _invoiceDate;
    private DateTime _paymentDate;

    public company buyer;
    public company vendor;
    public company reference;

    public lineItem[] items;
    public purchaseOrder()
    {
        _purchaseOrderStatus = purchaseOrderStates.ISSUED;
        _issuanceDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public void recordDelivery()
    {
        if (_purchaseOrderStatus == purchaseOrderStates.ISSUED)
        {
            _purchaseOrderStatus = purchaseOrderStates.DELIVERED;
            _deliveryDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    public void recordInvoice()
    {
        if (_purchaseOrderStatus == purchaseOrderStates.DELIVERED)
        {
            _purchaseOrderStatus = purchaseOrderStates.INVOICED;
            _invoiceDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    public void recordPayment()
    {
        if (_purchaseOrderStatus == purchaseOrderStates.INVOICED)
        {
            _purchaseOrderStatus = purchaseOrderStates.PAID;
            _issuanceDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where is this "xml"-file created? You need to include the code, it's probably somewhere in that code you'll find your answer.

Comment: `_issuanceDate` is set in the `purchaseOrder` method, `_deliveryDate` is set in the `recordDelivery` method and `_invoiceDate` is set in the `recordInvoice` method. `_paymentDate` is not set, but was probably intended to be set in the `recordPayment` method.

Comment: but i never called these methods !

Answer (score 0):

_issuanceDate is set in purchaseOrder constructor

```
_issuanceDate = DateTime.Now;
```

All other dates go with default values.

Comment: but how and when are the methods being called because i havent called them, but the author claims that _puchasOrderStatus becomes PAID.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare an instance of purchaseOrder `purchaseOrder po = new purchaseOrder();` in your `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` this will call purchaseOrder constructor:

```
public purchaseOrder()
{
    _purchaseOrderStatus = purchaseOrderStates.ISSUED;
    _issuanceDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

And this will initiate `_purchaseOrderStatus` and `_issuanceDate` .